# SignalR client not firing server code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

i am testing this signal with a very basic string. But the client side is not firing the server code and there is no error. i added the `[HubName("MyHub1")]` and the `[HubMethodName("GetValueString")]` in because if not the javascript will complaint client undefine and methodname not found.

after i added this 2 meta in. there is no error but server code was not fire. Anyone help please.

Client Script

```
(function () {
    // Defining a connection to the server hub.
    debugger
    var myHub = $.connection.MyHub1;
    // Setting logging to true so that we can see whats happening in the browser console log. [OPTIONAL]
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    // Start the hub
    $.connection.hub.start();

    // This is the client method which is being called inside the MyHub constructor method every 3 seconds
    myHub.client.GetValueString = function (serverTime) {
        // Set the received serverTime in the span to show in browser
        $("#newTime").html(serverTime);
    };
}());
```

Server script

```
[HubName("MyHub1")]
public class MyHub1 : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.hello();
    }
    [HubMethodName("GetValueString")]
    public void Getstring() {
        var taskTimer = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                //Sending the server time to all the connected clients on the client method ()
                Clients.All.GetValueString("test");
                //Delaying by 3 seconds.
                await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
          );


    }
}
```

Update 1
so i change my javascript to this and the output was "undefine" but no error also

> var haha = myHub.client.GetValueString;
>               // Set the received serverTime in the span to show in browser
>   [image]

Comment: What fires your `Getstring()` ? 

maybe do something like `myHub.server.Getstring` and remove `[HubMethodName("GetValueString")]`

Comment: Have you also made sure to set `app.MapSignalR();`

Comment: still same error as the picture show on top. yes o added the app.mappsignalr() at     `public partial class Startup` startup.cs

Comment: same error.after removing the ` [HubMethodName("GetValueString")]`  and put my code inside the `.done`. i can confirm this as i put a alert() message in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give this ago. Also, use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) for reference

I've added a `console.log` try and see if you see it when you run this code.

```
(function () {

    var myHub = $.connection.MyHub1;

    myHub.client.GetValueString = function (serverTime) {

        $("#newTime").html(serverTime);
    };

    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        console.log("hub is ready"); // tell me if you see the message in your console log
        myHub.server.getstring() // note i wrote getstring with a small g, has to be.
    });


}());

[HubName("MyHub1")]
public class MyHub1 : Hub
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.hello();
    }

    public void Getstring() {
        var taskTimer = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                //Sending the server time to all the connected clients on the client method ()
                Clients.All.GetValueString("test");
                //Delaying by 3 seconds.
                await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
          );


    }
}
```

Comment: it works !!! give me few minutes to compare the code differences. Thanks so muchhhh

Comment: `myHub.client.GetValueString = function (serverTime) {

            $("#newTime").html(serverTime);
        };` just a quick question. why is this line called before hub start?

Comment: This line is a Reciever line, so it dont matter where you put it, so i normally just put it before my "sending" lines, aka so i dont mix them up